# Why are no more Perl 6 questions asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

It seemed to have stopped somewhere in October 2019.  I thought that development of Perl 6 was still going on.  So why are there no more people asking questions about Perl 6?

Comment: Technically speaking, questions *about* the site belong on [meta]. But I see this is intended as a signpost, and moving it to meta will create unnecessary work and noise. But just mentioning this for your future reference.

Comment: @Dan Bron: thanks for the reminder and your understanding.  Yes, I realized it was bending the rules a bit.  But this is an extraordinary situation, that I hope never to have to go through again.

Comment: You can suggest [tag:raku] as a tag synonym for [tag:perl6] here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl6/synonyms

Comment: I think marking it as a synonym, would defeat the purpose of distancing Raku from the "Perl" brand, which is what most people in the Perl community want.

Comment: Regardless though, a synonym might be very helpful for the community.  There 1184 questions using the [tag:perl6],  314 of which also use [tag:raku] and another 384 that use [tag:raku] alone.  This creates a messy situation where people can't find questions unless they know the 2 different tags.  At a minimum, this meta question should be edited into the tag wiki and except for [tg:perl6]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Perl 6 community has decided that the "Perl 6 Programming Language" will be called the "Raku Programming Language" instead.

Since this decision, all Perl 6 questions that have been asked here with the [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6) tag have been re-tagged as [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) and have had their [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6)tag removed.

So, please if you have any questions about the language formerly known as "Perl 6", please ask them using the [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) tag.

Comment: Tag [tag:perl6] is now a synonym of tag [tag:raku]. Using either tag will result in the question being tagged [tag:raku].

Comment: Note: There are a number of Perl5 modules that implement "Perl6-like" behaviours, for example https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form . So it's very important that these "Perl6" posts don't get tagged "Raku" but instead are tagged "Perl", "Perl5" or "Perl7", etc.